# java - having a problem with sorting an arraylist of stack of Integer

Tags: java

Currently i am trying to create a method to sort an arraylist of stack of integer lexicographical  for my assignment. Currently this is what i had, however, right now i am facing a problem.

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Stack<Integer>>(){
            public int compare(Stack<Integer> list1, Stack<Integer> list2){
                int result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= list1.size() - 1 && result == 0; i++)
                {
                    result = list2.get(i).compareTo(list1.get(i));
                }
                return result;
            }
        });
```

When i try to input `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4], [4, 1, 4], [4, 4, 1], [3, 3, 3]]` as the arraylist of stack of integer and manage to get this as the result:

Output: `[[4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 4], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`

As you can see that is not lexicographic and this is what i am aiming for

Expected output: `[[1, 4, 4], [3, 3, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 4, 1], [1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`

Here is the question, Where did i get it wrong? how does .compareTo works?

**Edit:**

Apparently, my professor make a misunderstanding on the meaning of lexicographically. However, the expected output is the output what my professor desire

Comment: What do you mean with lexicographically?

Comment: An order that follows an order of alphabetical order or in this case, number. For example if i have a list of [[1,2,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,1],[1,1,2,1]] if i order it it would be [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,1,2,1]]

Comment: Your expected output doesn't look  lexicographically to me. With letters, it would mean that "Zoe" comes before "Adam" because "Zoe" has less letters. Are you sure this is right?

Comment: Huh if you put it that way you are right. However, i guess my professor mistook the meaning of lexicography. The output and expected output is what my professor desire.  I am going to make an edit to straight out the misunderstanding.

Comment: 9 out 10 ten times when I thought my professor was wrong, it actually turned out to be I didn't understand what he said. For your consideration,  [2] woud be less than [1,0] if you order by array length: 1 less than 2. [1,0] would be less than [2] if you order by the elements taken as characters of a string: string "10" is smaller than string "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first check if one of the stacks is shorter than the other. If not you need to compare the elements of `list1` against `list2`, not the other way around.

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Stack<Integer>>(){
  public int compare(Stack<Integer> list1, Stack<Integer> list2){
      int result = Integer.compare(list1.size(), list2.size());
      for (int i = 0; result == 0 && i < list1.size(); i++)
      {
        result = Integer.compare(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
      }
      return result;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an assignment I will put you on what I think is the right direction, but I won't solve the programming for you:

`compare()` is a method defined in the interface `Comparator<T>` that is supposed to return `-1, 0, or 1` depending if the first object passed in as a parameter is less, equal, or greater than the second object passed in as a parameter.

The expected objects are of type `T` which you define when you declare the class.

In the `compare()` method you write, you have to resolve whatever comparison method you want to implement, to a `-1, a 0, or a 1`.

How you get to those values depends on how you evaluate an object of `T` type to be less, equal or greater than other object of the same type.

On another side, `Array.sort()` will use the `Comparator` as fit to make comparisons between two elements of the array, and return as a final result the ordered `Array`.

If I understood your clarification, an `array [1,1,1]`, for ordering purposes should be interpreted as a `String "111"`;

So in terms of programming the `Comparator`, what will be compared (the `T`) would be `arrays` of `integers`.

And to compare two `arrays` of `integers`, the elements of each array should be extracted and sticked together to form a `String`. Once you have both `Strings`, you can see how they compare to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If our concepts of lexicographically ordered is the same, looks like the problem is that you are using compareTo inverted (list2 compareTo list1 instead of list1 compareTo list2).

After some modifications your code will look like this:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Stack<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Stack<Integer> list1, Stack<Integer> list2) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= list1.size() - 1 && result == 0; i++) {
            if (list2.size()-1 < i)
                return 1;
            else
                result = list1.get(i).compareTo(list2.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

This code will produce the following result: `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 4], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 4, 1]]`, that I understand as lexicographically ordered despite of your expected result.

The `if (list2.size()-1 < i)` inside the for loop prevents an IndexOutOfBoundsException due to list2 being smaller than list1.